# How do I add Angular-Chart.JS data into UI-Router .State Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-ui-router, angular-chart

**What I'm attempting to do:**
I'm building a single-page app using Angular UI-Router. One of my pages has a line chart so I am using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).

**What I don't understand:**
I don't understand how to get the charts to show inside the UI-Router state.  I can get the graph to work if I don't include it into a single-page app.  I have a feeling I need to add a controller to the UI-Router state containing the $scope labels, series and data, but I haven't been able to get it to work properly.

**Angular-Chart.js Code**

```
var chartApp = angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js']);

chartApp.controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    'use strict';   
    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Motivation', 'Workload'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
});
```

**UI-Router Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';

    // For any unmatched url, redirect home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    // chart page
    .state('charts', {
        url: '/charts',
        templateUrl: 'app/charts.html'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, the controller has to be instantiated on the chart template, either by ng-init or by adding it to the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get Immanuel's code to work for me, but he led me on the right track to use views. I read up on multiple views using UI Router from this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router. Almost immediately, I was able to get it to work.

The charts.html page called the ui-view:

`<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="line-chart" ui-view="line-chart"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="bar-chart" ui-view="bar-chart"></div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="doughnut-chart" ui-view="doughnut-chart"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="radar-chart" ui-view="radar-chart"></div>
    </div>`

**My app.js code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'chart.js']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';

    // For any unmatched url, redirect home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    // charts page
    .state('charts', {
        url: '/charts',
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: 'app/charts.html', },
            'line-chart@charts': {
                templateUrl: 'app/charts-line.html',
                controller: 'lineController'
            },
            "bar-chart@charts": {
                templateUrl: 'app/charts-bar.html',
                controller: 'barController'
            },
            "doughnut-chart@charts": {
                templateUrl: 'app/charts-doughnut.html',
                controller: 'doughnutController'
            },
            "radar-chart@charts": {
                templateUrl: 'app/charts-radar.html',
                controller: 'radarController'
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Then I called the controller for each.  Here is the line chart:

```
// Define the charts controller called from the charts state
myApp.controller('lineController', function($scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.message = 'There should be a line chart here:';
    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Motivation', 'Workload'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
});
```

And that was it!

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript code, you did not include the controller. It should be:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';

    // For any unmatched url, redirect home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    // chart page
    .state('charts', {
        url: '/charts',
        templateUrl: 'app/charts.html'
        controller: 'LineCtrl'
    });
});
```

Although, there is a better way than this. You could resolve the data coming from a service so that the page would wait for that data before it shows the compiled html.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'someService']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';

    // For any unmatched url, redirect home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    // chart page
    .state('charts', {
        url: '/charts',

        //I use the 'views' property to ready my code for nested views as well as to
        //isolate the properties for each view on that particular url
        views: {
            '':{
                templateUrl: 'app/charts.html',
                controller: 'LineCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'lineCtrl',
                resolve:{
                    labels: function(someService){
                        return someService.getAllLabels();
                    },
                    series: function(someService){
                        return someService.getAllSeries();
                    },
                    data: function(someService){
                        return someService.getAllData();
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
var chartApp = angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js']);

chartApp.controller("LineCtrl", ['$scope', 'labels', 'series', 'data', function ($scope, labels, series, data) {
    'use strict';   
    $scope.labels = labels;
    $scope.series = series;
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Immanuel, thanks for the insight.  I hadn't thought to use views.  That would allow me to create multiple graphs and call them from the HTML with `<div ui-view=""></div>`, correct?  I'll give this a shot.